# PHP - Yii2 variable scope

Tags: php, scope, yii2

I have simple PHP code like this:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\bvh\BvhFiles;
use app\models\bvh\BvhCategories;

class BvhController extends Controller {

    public function actionView($id) {

//        $cache = $cache = Yii::$app->getCache();

        $BvhFile = BvhFiles::getDb()->cache(function ($db) {
            return BvhFiles::find()->where(['OR', 'id=' . $id, 'YoutubeId=' . $id])->one();
        });
```

But it's not work. It fails with

> PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> Undefined variable: id

at

```
 return BvhFiles::find()->where(['OR', 'id=' . $id, 'YoutubeId=' . $id])->one();
```

How should I pass $id variable to this code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply try this :

```
$BvhFile = BvhFiles::getDb()->cache(function ($db) use ($id) {
    return BvhFiles::find()->where(['OR', 'id=' . $id, 'YoutubeId=' . $id])->one();
});
```

Read more about [anonymous function and how to use variables from the parent scope](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-197).

And you should use this ([read more](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where()-detail)) :

```
return BvhFiles::find()->where(['OR', ['id' => $id], ['YoutubeId' => $id]])->one();
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a problem not related to Yii, but to php itself. If you want to pass a variable down to an anonymous function you need to use the `use` keyword:

```
$BvhFile = BvhFiles::getDb()->cache(function ($db) use($id) {
    return BvhFiles::find()->where(['OR', 'id=' . $id, 'YoutubeId=' . $id])->one();
});
```